# Angular Components with @Input being used in a different module to which it is declared in

Tags: angular

I have the following component which has an @Input declared:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-api-error-message',
  templateUrl: './api-error-message.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./api-error-message.component.scss'],
  inputs: ['ErrorMessages']
})

export class ApiErrorMessageComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() ErrorMessages: ErrorMessage[];

  constructor(private router: Router, private _location: Location) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

This component is declared and exported in the app module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ApiErrorMessageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MyOtherModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ApiErrorMessageComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am trying to use the ApiErrorMessageComponent in a component declared in 'MyOtherModule'.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MyOtherRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class MyOtherModule { }
```

MyComponent.html:

```
<app-api-error-message [ErrorMessages]="errorData"></app-api-error-message>
```

But I get the following error message:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR

MyComponent.component.html:2:3 - error NG8001: 'app-api-error-message' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-api-error-message' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-api-error-message' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

2   <app-api-error-message [ErrorMessages]="errorData"></app-api-error-message>
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  MyComponent.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: './MyComponent.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component MyComponent.


ERROR

MyComponent.component.html:2:26 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ErrorMessages' since it isn't a known property of 'app-api-error-message'.
1. If 'app-api-error-message' is an Angular component and it has 'ErrorMessages' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-api-error-message' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

2   <app-api-error-message [ErrorMessages]="errorData"></app-api-error-message>
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  MyComponent.component.ts:9:16
    9   templateUrl: './MyComponent.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component MyComponent.
```

Any ideas what I am missing......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice the `imports` object of your `MyOtherModule` module only contains modules? You must add `AppModule` to the `imports` of `MyOtherModule` in order to use the components `AppComponent` exports inside of the `MyOtherModule` module.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MyOtherRoutingModule,
    AppModule // IMPORTANT !!!!
  ]
})
export class MyOtherModule { }
```

Usually, in big applications you have a few modules corresponding to the natural modules of your respective application field. If a component needs to be shared between modules, it's probably wise to create a CommonModule that is imported in all other modules.

Comment: When I add `AppComponent` to the imports of the `MyOtherModule`, I get an the error `Class AppComponent is not an Angular module`. So I assume you meant `AppModule` but I then get a Cyclic dependency error `Cyclic dependency between modules: MyOtherModule-> AppModule -> MyOtherModule`

Comment: I apologize. I do mean `AppModule`. Cyclic dependency is quite clear. You cannot import module `A` into module `B` and then module `B` into module `A`. You will need to restructure your modules and components.

Comment: I was hoping you wasn't going to say that

Comment: Sorry. :D As I said, you could put this component in a different module which is shared between these two in which you want to use it.

Comment: wait why `MyOtherModule` should import `AppModule`? Sounds strage!

Answer (score 0):

In this can I would suggest you follow SCAM (Single Component Angular Module) pattern.

**SCAM** -

- each component has its own NgModule
- wherever it is going to use a component, consumers of components have to import the newly created `NgModule` in their `NgModule`.
- It helps to isolate the component
- Step helps you to move forward toward [**Standalone Components**](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components)

---

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ApiErrorMessageComponent],
  exports: [ApiErrorMessageComponent],
  import: [
    CommonModule,
    ...
  ],
})
export class ErrorMessageModule {

}
```

And when it comes to usage, import `ErrorMessageModule` in NgModule whichever place you wanted to use `ApiErrorMessageComponent`. Like here it would be imported in

1. `imports` of `MyOtherModule`
2. `imports` of `AppModule`